# Как правильно преобразовать с помощь стрима?

Tags: java, java-stream

Есть класс

```
public class Entity {
   private String firstName;

public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
   }
```

Есть класс Item, который содержит поле Entity entity:

```
public class Item {
    private Entity entity;
 public Entity getEntity() {
        return entity;
    }
```

Есть ArraList items. Хочу из него с помощью стрима получить список всеx firstName. Пишу такой код, но AndroidStudio на него ругается:

```
List<String> items = Item.items.stream().map(item -> item.getEntity().getFirstName().toString()).toArray();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас странная система именования, непонятно откуда в классе `Item` берутся `items` и непонятно, почему вы стрим преобразовываете в массив, а присваивать результат пытаетесь списку. Предположим, что `items` - это `List<Item>`, тогда:

```
List<String> firstNames = items.stream()
                               .map(Item::getEntity)
                               .map(Entity::getFirstName)
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```